# How to update a React Native app made with Expo to a newer version?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

At the company I work for, we have an app used only internally that is needing some updates. The problem is, the source code that we have is very old and several libs are out of date, including Expo SDK.

Is there a way to successfully update the app to a functional newer version? What do I update first and how to check which lib version is compatible and which is not?

Here is the original package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|native-base))"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-image-crop": "^0.2.17",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.0.1",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.6.2",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mobx": "^5.6.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-auto-height-image": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.27",
    "react-native-masonry": "^0.5.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "https://github.com/Osedea/react-native-material-dropdown.git",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^36.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've already tried to update the Expo SDK from the version 36 to version 41 directly, but that created some incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Moving from Expo v36 to the latest will take some time but it is doable.

The "official way" would be to incrementally upgrade to v37, v38, v39 ...., v49.  But a problem with that is that everything before v46 is no longer actively supported.

When I upgraded from v35, I did it one version at a time until v40, then I was able to jump a few versions at a time.  That was 2 years ago.  I just don't know if that is worth doing all the way back to v36.

If this were me, I'd likely create a brand new Expo project with the latest-n-greatest (`npx create-expo-app <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE>`), copy the files from your old project's `src` folder to the new folder, for each of the dependencies of your old project listed in `package.json` I'd install them into the new project using `npx expo install <.....>` (probably best one at a time).

You might take this upgrade as an opportunity to update some of your code.  Some of those older `react-native-....` dependencies might now be deprecated or superceded by newer libraries...possibly even some Expo-specific ones.

One thing to note from your original project: you have a number of NPMs installed as `dependencies` that really should be `devDependencies` instead.  The difference is whether you install them using `npx expo install ....` or `npx expo install --save-dev ....`.  `dependencies` are for NPMs that are directly used by your app, whereas `devDependencies` are things used only during development, testing and build.  For example, `eslint` and its plugins are almost certainly devDependencies for your app, not used inside your app itself.

As you are doing your upgrade, you might find that hanging out in the Expo Developers server on Discord is worthwhile.  Lots of folks there who have been through these upgrades and have the scars to help you avoid the wounds.